# How to get all my mega.nz account folder names?

Tags: python, dictionary, mega-api

I am using mega.nz API and I want to get all of my mega folder NAMES.

I have done this:

```
files = m.get_files()
print(files)
```

And my output is this:

```
'5Xxl1YpK': {'h': '5Xxl1YpK', 'p': '5apkxBRK', 'u': 'HeQAbozUSnY', 't': 1, 'a': {'n': 'MAIN'}, 'k': (236358726, 3714021502, 3609314937, 957702177), 'ts': 1649753591, 'shared_folder_key': (1341100632, 611479631, 4161937411, 5464436), 'key': (236358726, 3714021502, 3609314937, 957702177)}
```

I just want the name of the folder ("MAIN") and I don't know how to get it because it's not a normal dictionary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [How to access the values of a nested dictionary structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72015048/how-to-access-the-values-of-a-nested-dictionary-structure)