# How to access the values of a nested dictionary structure

Tags: python, nested

I have a nested dictionary structure and I want to iterate through it and print the values of each key within the nested key. For example:

```
    animals = {
        "Bear": {"food": "fish", "claws": "12"},
        "Tiger": {"food": "meat", "claws": "8"},
        "Elephant": {"food": "grass", "claws": "0"},
        "Chicken": {"food": "feed", "claws": "talons"},
        "Wolf": {"food": "rabbits", "claws": "6"}

    }

target_animal = "Tiger"
tfood = ?
tclaws = ?
print("A tiger's food: "+ tfood)
print("A tiger's claws: "+ tclaws)
```

I have tried iterating through

```
if inner dictionary name == target_animal: 
    for i in kingdom.keys():
        #print(i)
        for j in kingdom[i]:
            innerDict = (kingdom[i][j])
```

I do not know where to check for: if the inner dictionary name = "tiger", nor how to only access the values at the targeted inner dictionary.

The goal is to iterate through the 'animals' dictionary and if the key == the target_animal, print its inner dictionary values.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: You don't have to iterate the dictionaries keys and then compare if you got the right one. Just access the entry: `animal_data = animals['Tiger']`. That's the whole point of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to chain the brackets :

```py
animals = {
        "Bear": {"food": "fish", "claws": "12"},
        "Tiger": {"food": "meat", "claws": "8"},
        "Elephant": {"food": "grass", "claws": "0"},
        "Chicken": {"food": "feed", "claws": "talons"},
        "Wolf": {"food": "rabbits", "claws": "6"}

}

target_animal = "Tiger"
tfood = animals[target_animal]["food"]
tclaws = animals[target_animal]["claws"]
```

In the code above, you have `animals[target_animal]` which is equivalent to `{"food": "meat", "claws": "8"}`. This is itself a dictionary, so you can add the `["food"]` and `["claws"]` to access the value whitin.

Answer (score 0):

```
animals = {
        "Bear": {"food": "fish", "claws": "12"},
        "Tiger": {"food": "meat", "claws": "8"},
        "Elephant": {"food": "grass", "claws": "0"},
        "Chicken": {"food": "feed", "claws": "talons"},
        "Wolf": {"food": "rabbits", "claws": "6"}

    }
# if you just wanna query for one animal, then
target_animal = "Tiger"
target_dict = animals['Tiger'] 
#dtype of target_dict again is a dict, so you can #again use indexing
tfood = target_dict['food']
tclaws = target_dict['claws']
print("A tiger's food: "+ tfood)
print("A tiger's claws: "+ tclaws)
```

If you want to iterate through everything

```
for animal, props in animals.items():
    print(f"A {animal}'s food: {props['food']}")
    print(f"A {animal}'s claws: {props['claws']}")
```

If you want to use iteration and still filter out only for tiger, then

```
for animal, props in animals.items():
    if animal=='Tiger':
        print(f"A {animal}'s food: {props['food']}")
        print(f"A {animal}'s claws: {props['claws']}")
```